# How to make text starting from top left of textbox ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

How to make this text starting from the top left of textbox and without this cros on right side. TextBox is from MVC I would like to change it in CSS[image: screen]

Comment: How are you rendering (code) this textbox? As long as I understand you want to apply style or css class on it, is that correct?

Comment: @Html.TextBox("Napisz", null, new { @class = "napisz ostatni" })  i woud like to  make text starting from the top left of the box. I am just looking for solution, it  don't have to be done in CSS

Comment: Or maybe I should use different  MVC control?